# Node.js: How to handle MongoDB Write Error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection

How to handle MongoDB write error(due to **Mongo connection** drop) ? Because I have to do updates on multiple documents, so basically it needs to be transactional, "Nothing or all" approach. I thought I can catch the **err** and revert the inserted data if one of the updates was failed. But if the MongoDB connection dropped, it's directly caught by the "**uncaughtException**" of application. So how can I handle this scenario ? All I need is "Nothing or All" on a multi-document update.

Comment: There are no transactions in mongodb, but you can try [2-phase commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions don't exist in MongoDB. There are some workarounds, such as [the one @Alex-Blex posted in the comments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) where you do two-stage commits to progressively perform your update. (It's a bit of a misnomer; their example has seven db ops.)

> if the MongoDB connection dropped, it's directly caught by the "uncaughtException" of application

You can listen for this with the connection `disconnected` and `error` events:

```
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", function () {
    // Lost connection to database
});
mongoose.connection.on("reconnected", ...);
```

Usually those listeners are application-wide, although I suppose you could set one up for the lifetime of your "transaction". You'd have to wait for `reconnected`, and retry/resume your database op. In any case, you'll still be relying on your application to not crash for any reason for the entire duration of your "transaction."

If you need transactions to be reliable, probably need to look at another database.